# Firefox resets Javascript's variable's value

Tags: javascript, firefox, load, addeventlistener

I'm using Firefox 16.0.2.
I'm using an onload eventlistener to call a script which increases the value of a variable.
I need to get the variable's value before I increase it. Safari and  Chrome (Webkit) give the right result but Firefox always alerts "0"...

**This is my Script:**

```
var obj = {
    build: function() {
        var progressCount = 0; 
        var otherFunction = function(number) {
                alert(number);
        } 
        var finalFunction = function() {
                alert("done");
        } 
        var progress = function() {
                alert(progressCount);   //    !  very important line !
                progressCount++;
                otherFunction(progressCount);
                if (progressCount == ARRAY.length) {
                finalFunction();
                }
        }
        ARRAY=document.getElementsByClassName("picture")
        for (var i = 0; i < ARRAY.length; i++)
        ARRAY[i].addEventListener("load", progress);
    }
}
obj.build();
```

What else could I try?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I have a similar one in my project, with same approach, but it works. So can you post a more complete script?

Comment: Is all the code you provided in the global scope or is this within a function or something?

Comment: I just added the object and the function that contain my script, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Can you link to an actual page showing the problem?

Comment: It works when i just call progress; from within the loop so it seems to have something to do with the event listeners...